# Angular: How to go about refreshing service data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I am fairly new to Angular and trying to build an Angular application. 
I have a lot of data that needs to be used by multiple controllers throughout the app. As I understand it, that is the perfect situation to use a service.

I am planning on storing this kind of data in services. For example I plan on having a users service which all controllers that need user data will inject.

I would like the users service to hold the master list of users and any controller that needs users to just use the one instance of service list.

I am having trouble envisioning the pattern though. I mean:

1) What is the standard way of having the service refresh its data from the server? I realize that I could just go and request the entire list of users every 10 seconds from the server but that seems kind of heavy weight...

2) Ideally I would like to be passing around only a single instance of each user. This way if it gets updated in the service, it is sure to be updated in all of the controllers. I guess the  other option is to have the service broadcast an event every time it updates a user? or to use watchers?

3) What is the pattern by which the controllers interact with the service and filters? Do the controllers just request data from the service and filter it in the controller? The other option is to have the service do the filtering. If so how do I communicate the kind of filtering I need done to the service?

I think that by using some kind of solid pattern I can take care of alot of these issues (and more that I am sure will arise). Just looking for advice on some common patterns people employ when using singleton services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question really is dependent on understanding prototypal inheritance. Once you recognize that  with `var a=[] ;var b= a` there is only one array and each variable references the same array, service sharing is easier to understand. Service could be told to update that array at set interval, and controllers don't have to do anything to stay current

Answer (score 0):

Answer to point 1. A service is just a singleton. How you store and refresh data into it has nothing to do with its nature. Not sure why you want all user data inside a service (unless you are building a user management app), but you could use several techniques like polling (eg. using $timeout ask for new users and append them to the existing ones) or push (eg. socket.io/signalR which will push you the payload of new users when available). This can be done both inside the service itself or by a controller that will add/remove data to the service (eg. a refresh users button in the UI)

Answer to point 2. You can bind/use the reference of the data inside the service directly into your controllers using a getter so that changes to the data are shown instantly (given that are two way binded, if not use events).

Answer to point 3. You can apply filters inside the controllers or in the view it self (not recommended). You can also have a function in the service where you pass the filter or filter params and get the filtered copy of the users collection back (since you will be using the users collection directly in many controllers at once you shouldn't modify that, unless that's desired). If you are reusing the same filters again and again across the controllers you can have a function for each filter that returns the filtered collection with a "hardcoded" filter. You can even have helper function in the service to help you assemble complex filters or have multiple copies of the collection already filtered cached(if you find you are using the same filter again and again)